# How to locate an element using whole html(innerHtml) content

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to locate an element using whole html content such as `<a href="javascript:view_download_report(document.MForm, 'mm_tt_uu_999','~','D');">Download</a>`

Please help.

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35063568/5830773
with this you can split the whole html string

Comment: I have string variable such as string strTemp="<a href="javascript:view_download_report(document.MForm, 'mm_tt_uu_999','~','D');">Download</a>" how to find out with selenium?

Comment: can you update your post with more information? e.g. what you want to extract from the html

Answer (score 0):

use the below as cssSelector:

```
a[href*='view_download_report(document.MForm']
```

it will give u this element.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use xpath:

.//a[@href='javascript:view_download_report(document.MForm,
'mm_tt_uu_999','~','D')']